# Configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm carrying out the lab of the GCP platform "Configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager", i changed the qwicklabs.jinja for this code:

```
 resources:
- name: default-allow-http
  type: compute.v1.firewall
  properties:
    targetTags: ["http"]
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: ["80"]
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: vm-test
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/f1-micro
    # For examples on how to use startup scripts on an instance, see:
    #   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript
    tags:
        items: ["http"]
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: "apt-get update \n apt-get install -y apache2"
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      # Access Config required to give the instance a public IP address
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

The VM and Disk are made succesfully but i can't complete the last task "Check that Deployment manager includes startup script and firewall resource" because i have problems making the firewall rule an this appear:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1598852175371-5a
e25c7f61bda-1c55c951-22ca1242]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/deployment-templates/resources/http-firewall-rule
  message: '{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.firewall","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{
"code":400,"message":"Request
    contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/qwiklabs-gcp-01-888e7
df2843f/global/firewalls","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Could someone help me pls? I have to finish this lab!

Comment: Is your deployment shows on the list when you run `gcloud deployment-manager deployments list` ? Even without firewall rule it should be there.

Comment: yes, that's correct, the VM and the disk are correctly created, but not the firewall rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file was giving me for some reason "invalid format" error so I created a new Deployment Manager config file; took [VM template from here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-basic-configuration#declaring_resource_properties), added your external IP configuration and also firewall rule part (without any changes).

My yaml file looks like this (I didn't use any variables though).

```
resources:
- name: vm-created-by-deployment-manager
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-a
    machineType: zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    tags:
        items: ["http"]
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: "apt-get update \n apt-get install -y apache2"
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
- name: default-allow-http3
  type: compute.v1.firewall
  properties:
    targetTags: ["http"]
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: ["80"]
```

When I ran the file everything worked as intended:

```
wbogacz@cloudshell:~/fire (wojtek)$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments create test1 --config dm1.yaml
The fingerprint of the deployment is b'n63E-AtErTCKtWOvktfUsA=='
Waiting for create [operation-1599036146720-5ae5-----99-2a45880e-addbce89]...done.
Create operation operation-1599036146720-5ae-----99-2a45880e-addbce89 completed successfully.
NAME                              TYPE                 STATE      ERRORS  INTENT
default-allow-http3               compute.v1.firewall  COMPLETED  []
vm-created-by-deployment-manager  compute.v1.instance  COMPLETED  []
```

At the end I logged in via SSH to the VM and verified that the startup script was executed - and again success.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll use your code instead of mine and I going to tell you the results, however, i wish l knew what i did wrong whit my jinja file :/

Comment: By the way, sorry for this stupid question, but did you omitted the first line? I mean the line "resources:" and the line "name" whe you created the instance?

Comment: I added two missing lines - thanks for spotting that. I suspect only that variables in your file may have been the culprit but I would have time to try this out.. I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer &/or upvoted if it's usefull to you :)

Comment: .Yeah, thank you. I have already completed this lab. The real problem was in the .yaml file there was a firewall rule script already, so I was creating 2 firewall rules and in one of them there was a wrong tag, so the deployment threw an error

Comment: > "The real problem was in the .yaml file there was a firewall rule script already" <

This is the solution. The firewall rule in the YAML had error. Remove it and it works.
Thank You.